# How to copy and cut multiple lines in Emacs correctly?

Tags: spacemacs

I have researched it. Most post said this way:

```
C-SPC C-n M-w
```

It works. But in my case. It only copied a block where the cursor moved. Not the whole lines area I want.

For example, the source below:

```
1 def hi():
2    print("hi")
3 .  print("hi")
4    print("hi")
----------col:16
```

The operations I did:

1. At the beginning of line 1, click `C-x SPC` (Because I'm using macOS so `C-SPC` not work, the keys are conflict)
2. Move down using `C-n` until line 4
3. Click `C-e` to the end of the last line ensure to get all the area I want
4. Finally click `M-w` to copy them.
5. Paste them at other area by `C-y`. The line 1 likes `def hi():_____` with visible space

I can copy the content until col 16, but without the area afterward. So if I paste the content somewhere, the layout went bad.

---

Key conflict

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the file you had, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: @zck Yes, I edited it.

Comment: @phils I edited the question again. Is it clear now?

Comment: How often do you change the keyboard input source. I would expect most people to bne monolingual and never change their keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `C-x SPC` does something different from `C-SPC` - it is bound to `rectangle-mark-mode`, which causes the behaviour you're seeing: the selection is rectangular, rather than a range of text.

One thing you can do is using `C-@` instead of `C-SPC` - both are bound to `set-mark-command` by default.  Or you could find some other key binding that's convenient for you, and set it in your Emacs init file.  For example, use Control-Tab with:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<tab>") 'set-mark-command)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a very clear answer!